# Extract data based the condition using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (df):

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1Q |
| 124 | B | L1 |
| 125 | B | QW |
| 126 | A | E2 |

If the user selects a particular column and the value the entire row should be saved as a new dataframe. For example, if the user selects Col_A 123 the output should be the following:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1Q |

If the user selects Col_B: B and Col_A: 125 then the output should e the following:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | B | QW |

If the user selects Col_B: B then the output shoud be the following:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | B | L1 |
| 125 | B | QW |

How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.read_csv('Table.csv')
print('Enter the value as 99 if the Col_A or Col_B is not known')
Col_A_value= (input(str("Enter tag of your interest separated by ',': ")).split(","))
Col_B_value= (input(str("Enter iris_image_id of your interest separated by ',': ")).split(","))
input_table = []
for i,j in itertools.product(Col_A_value, Col_B_value):
    if len(i) > 0 and len(j)==0:
        input_table.append(df[df['Col_A'] == i])
    elif i != '99' and len(j)> 0:
        input_table.append(df[df['Col_A'] == i])
```

The above script does not extract a particular data if Col_A and Col_B are specified. If I specify Col_A = 124 and Col_B = B it results everything in col_B.

Desired output:

| Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | B | L1 |

Comment: Could you clarify if I am following this correctly? You nest loop both user lists but check if a has a value and b is empty to check only on a. Otherwise if a is known and a value for b is entered save row if a matches. To me the logic is really weird, why do you never check the value of B, where is the 99 case handled. I would personally approach it as get A value, get b value, check if 99 or empty so ignore, else filter to append.

Comment: Well, you are referencing "Col_A" in both the "if" and "elif" calls.  Probably need to change the second "Col_A" to "Col_B".

Comment: This question on [panda data frame filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371788/filter-a-pandas-dataframe-through-a-dictionary#44375202) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Importing Libraries
import pandas as pd

# Importing dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')


# Col A Value input as int
first_input = int(input('Enter Col A Value'))

# Col B value input as string
second_input = str(input('Enter Col B Value'))

# checking both column values with == sign 
df[(df['Col_A'] == first_input) & (df['Col_B']== second_input)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this  :

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
print(df[(df['col1']==1) & (df['col2']==3)])
```

Result :
[image]

----------- OR --------

Try to use the pandas function where ([link to pandas.where tuto](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-where/)), It is better to use function than loops